# Only approve the row that is checked from asp gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

i have a gridview that looks like this wherein i have several rows : name, contact#, company name etc. and i have included a check box so i can choose what row to approve or not.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" EnableViewState="False"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
            SortExpression="Username" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="EmailAddress" 
            SortExpression="EmailAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyAddress" HeaderText="CompanyAddress" 
            SortExpression="CompanyAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="IncomeRange" HeaderText="IncomeRange" 
            SortExpression="IncomeRange" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditRequest" HeaderText="CreditRequest" 
            SortExpression="CreditRequest" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="ContactNumber" SortExpression="ContactNumber" />

        <%--<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>--%>


                <%--</ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>--%>

           <asp:CheckBoxField />
           <asp:CheckBoxField />

    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Approve" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

what i want to happen is when i click on approve button, the only row that is checked will perform the code behind.

here is my code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            scn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username=@Username", scn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DSession["New"];

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE ( I tried this, it has no errors but the Approve function is not performing)

```
protected void Approve(string Username)
    {
        using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            scn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username=@Username", scn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //Searching CheckBox("chkDel") in an individual row of Grid  
            CheckBox chkdel = (CheckBox)grow.FindControl("chkDel");
            //If CheckBox is checked than delete the record with particular empid  
            if (chkdel.Checked)
            {
                string Username = grow.Cells[1].Text;
                Approve(Username);
            }
        }
        //Displaying the Data in GridView  
        bindgrid(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DataKeyNames="ur Primary column"` In `Gridview HTML`. 
And in code behind just loop through all the rows in GridView like below.

```
//Loop through all the rows in gridview
foreach (GridViewRow grv in grdEmp.Rows)
{
//Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)grv.FindControl("chkDel");

if (chk.Checked)
{
//get EmpId from DatakeyNames from gridview
int empid = Convert.ToInt32(grdEmp.DataKeys[grv.RowIndex].Value);

cmd = new SqlCommand("Update_Sp", con); //Put ur Inline query here
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Username; //use as per ur requirments
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
grdEmp.EditIndex = -1; 
BindEmpGrid();
```

Comment: @ReineViray: try by replacing  `string Username = grow.Cells[1].Text;` with `string Username = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Values["Username"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
 if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chkrow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkrow") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox);
    if (chkrow.Checked)
     {
      string Username = dgvshow.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString()
      Approve(Username);

     }
  }
}
```

and also use `!ispostback` in page load where you load your grid